# Are there disadvantages to using VARCHAR(MAX) in a table?

Tags: sql-server, varchar, nvarchar

Here is my predicament.

Basically, I need a column in a table to hold up an unknown length of characters. But I was curious if in Sql Server performance problems could arise using a VARCHAR(MAX) or NVARCHAR(MAX) in a column, such as: 'This time' I only need to store 3 characters and most of the time I only need to store 10 characters. But there is a small chances that It could be up to a couple thousand characters in that column, or even possibly a million, It is unpredictable. But, I can guarantee that it will not go over the 2GB limit.

I was just curious if there are any performance issues, or possibly better ways of solving this problem where available.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Sounds to me like you plan to use the varchar(MAX) data type for its intended purpose.

When data in a MAX data type exceeds 8 KB, an over-flow page is used. SQL Server 2005 automatically assigns an over-flow indicator to the page and knows how to manipulate data rows the same way it manipulates other data types.

For further reading, check out Books Online: [char and varchar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089(SQL.90).aspx)

Comment: Whilst entirely right, I would avoid using the term overflow, since the Row-Overflow is the page type name for the varchar(n), whilst varchar(max) goes to a 'Lob Data' page type when viewed using DBCC Ind.

Comment: So the answer to the question 'are there any performance issues'? Is that no - maybe just a insignifant bit when it's overflowing? Is this correct?

Answer (score 11):

You cannot create indexes on `varchar(max)` ( and `nvarchar(max)`) columns (although they can be included in them. But who would include a column in an index that could get to 2GB?!) so if you want to search on this value, you will do a scan each time unless you use full-text indexes. Also, remember that any report designer or presentation designer (web or otherwise) must assume that someone might put the Encyclopedia into that column and design around it. Nothing is worse than hearing "the users probably won't do X". If a user can do it, they will do it. If a user can put in a tome into a column, at some point they will. If they never should, then IMO, it makes more sense to cap the column size at some reasonable level and if a user tries to stuff more into that column that is allowed, it would elicit a discussion of whether they should be entering that value into that column in the first place.

Comment: I strongly disagree.  In my experience, it's a frequent occurrence for users to legitimately run up against arbitrary size limits.  OTOH, I've never seen a single complaint about someone copying an entire encyclopedia into a form.

Comment: @dan04 - IME, developers frequently do not spend the time to get a spec on the actual intention of a column. The problem with setting no limit is that users put crap into a column because they can and then complain when their reports are fubar'ed or that the screen loads slow or that they put FirstName LastName into a single field and now they cannot sort by last name etc so you need to stop what you are doing and fix their data.  Without some limit, there is nothing that will indicate, until it is too late, that someone is trying to stuff something into a column that shouldn't be there.

Comment: The problem is that there are people who *actually have* 40-letter multiple-hyphenated last names, and complain when you try to force it into a VARCHAR(16).

Comment: @dan04 - On one thing we agree: I hate arbitrary size limits. The key word here is *arbitrary*. That means that the developer never consulted the client or any other source as to the most correct size for a given column. Thus, while we agree that varchar(16) for a last name is too small, I would also argue that varchar(max) for a last name is equally if not more idiotic.

Answer (score 4):

I just saw [this](http://rusanu.com/2010/03/22/performance-comparison-of-varcharmax-vs-varcharn/) article the other day. It documents a fairly minor performance lag for varchar(max) over a varchar(n) column. Probably not enough to make a difference for you. But if it does, perhaps you can use a separate table to store those few large text blocks. Your small text could stay in the main table, but you could add a flag field to tell you to look in the new table for the big ones.

Answer (score 4):

I've seen some problems - particularly with scalar functions (but these are generally horrible, anyway) which return varchar(MAX) and then aren't re-cast.  For instance, say you have a special function CleanString(somevarcharmax) returns varchar(max) and call it on varchar(50) but don't CAST(CleanString(varchar10col) AS varchar(10)) - nasty performance issues.

But typically, when you have varchar(max) columns in a table, you shouldn't be performing those kinds of operations en masse, so I'd say if you are using it properly for your data needs in the table, then it's fine.

Answer (score 1):

Crystal Reports 12 (and other versions, as far as I know) doesn't handle varchar(max) properly and interprets it as varchar(255) which leads to truncated data in reports.

So if you're using Crystal Reports, thats a disadvantage to varchar(max). Or a disadvantage to using Crystal, to be precise.

See:
http://www.crystalreportsbook.com/Forum/forum_posts.asp?TID=5843&PID=17503
http://michaeltbeeitprof.blogspot.com/2010/05/crystal-xi-and-varcharmax-aka-memo.html

Answer (score -3):

No, varchar(max) adjusts itself based on the size of the entry, so it is the most efficient if you will be using widely varied sized inputs.

Comment: varchar(max), no matter how little information is put, actually allocates n btyte length + 2 bytes, but the actual penalty is the fact that it won't allow column indexing, even if consuming just one byte of data. That's too inefficient for the sake of covering up a lack of data structure planning.