# Use of varchar(max)

Tags: sql-server, database, sqldatatypes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are there any disadvantages to always using nvarchar(MAX)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148398/are-there-any-disadvantages-to-always-using-nvarcharmax)
>   [varchar(max) everywhere?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091284/varcharmax-everywhere)

Given the fact that varchar will always store the actual amount of characters it has, not its size (for example, a varchar(10) column containing  "Hello" will only occupy 5 bytes), why not create all VARCHAR columns as varchar(max)?

Ok, there is the index issue where only columns with max of 900 bytes can be indexed, so why not create all the columns as varchar(900) or all the columns that are not due to be indexed as varchar(max) and the others as varchar(max)

Comment: you mean, also the non-string columns? so for example to sum the integer columns you have to convert them? nah.

Comment: no no..all the string columns, the ones I would normally create as varchar(50) or varchar(100)

Comment: `varchar` has an overhead over `char`, to begin with. if you have a zipcode column that you know it will always store 5 chars, then why declare it `varchar(900)`? makes no sense. also, the size of the column is a source of **information** for both the readers and the db.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091284/varcharmax-everywhere

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/858245/overhead-of-varcharmax-columns-with-small-data

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2572649/are-there-disadvantages-to-using-varcharmax-in-a-table

Comment: I never mentioned CHAR @vulkanino

Answer (score 0):

I don't know all the details, but it has to do with how disk space is allocated.  Is a link with some of the details.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190969.aspx