# Performance issues with varchar(max)?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are there disadvantages to using VARCHAR(MAX) in a table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2572649/are-there-disadvantages-to-using-varcharmax-in-a-table)

If I know that the column real size is only up to 100 chars but I still want to use nvarchar(max). What should be the performance cost and why?

Comment: It doesn't matter on how many records you currently have. In the long run you will have that amount of records. By the way 8k is very very small.

Comment: why this is dupliate? no one explaind why we have performance issues..

Comment: @dima did you *read* the answers in the linked question? Did you follow all of the links and read those too?

Comment: Also you say "I still want to use nvarchar(max)" - if you only need up to 100 characters, can you explain WHY you want to use nvarchar(max)?

Comment: i just want to know what are the overheads ... the "WHY" is not important i just want to understand why this creates performance problems :(